# return TRUE if *any* of columns chosen using tidyselect contains() is TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several variables which are booleans. I want to create a variable using mutate() which will be TRUE if *any* of the variables, selected based on their column name, are also true.

I have tried the following.

```
mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = select(contains("var")), isTRUE(.)))
```

isTRUE() does not receive the variables in the way i'd hope. Is there a different tidyverse way of structuring this, or a different function I can use to get the desired result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `select` - if we want to use `isTRUE`, use `rowwise` and then `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = contains('var'), isTRUE)) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or without `rowwise`, use the `I` (identical as these are logical columns)

```
dat %>%
    mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = contains('var'), I))
```

Or without any function as these are logical

```
dat %>%
     mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = contains('var')))
   var1  var2  var3 anyTRUE
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE    TRUE
2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE    TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
    var2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), var3 = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have tried the following now 
`library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = contains('var'), ~ isTRUE(.)))`
this still returns false for all variables - I have checked that the variables being checked are all logical and not strings, for some reason its not evaluating as any but rather as all?

Comment: @jurqchicken please try the update (I updated with a reproducible example)

Comment: that works, thank you @akrun! could you explain `I` please? i havent seen this in documentation before and can't see where to read more.

Comment: @jurqchicken it is for Identity i.e. your columns are logical.  You don't really need any function there.  I just used a placeholder.  i.e. `mutate(anyTRUE = if_any(.cols = contains('var')))` should work as well because these are logical

Comment: @akrun I have a followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73115768/checking-if-any-value-of-a-subset-of-columns-for-each-row-of-a-data-frame-is-tru 
as I have a question that is essentially seeking a more robust solution.